# Terraform - How to sort list of maps by key

Tags: terraform

How can I sort a list of maps/objects by a specific key in Terraform?

Example:

```
[
  {"name":"b", "value":"some value"},
  {"name":"c", "value":"some value"},
  {"name":"a", "value":"some value"},
  {"name":"d", "value":"some value"}
]
```

Desired output

```
[
  {"name":"a", "value":"some value"},
  {"name":"b", "value":"some value"},
  {"name":"c", "value":"some value"},
  {"name":"d", "value":"some value"}
]
```

Comment: if you convert this into a `map` type instead of `list(map)`, then it will automatically be sorted. You would also need to fix the structure though.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you should do?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to sort by `name`, Matt's comment is best. But if you want something else, e.g. sorting by `value` with possible duplicates, you can do it as follows:

```
locals {

   in_list = [
    {"name":"b", "value":"some value3"},
    {"name":"c", "value":"some value1"},
    {"name":"a", "value":"some value5"},
    {"name":"d", "value":"some value5"}
  ]
  
  #get sorted values (not names) with possible duplicates
  sorted_values = distinct(sort(local.in_list[*].value))

  sorted_list = flatten(
        [for value in local.sorted_values:
            [ for elem in local.in_list: 
                 elem if value == elem.value
            ]     
        ]) 
}
```